# Jquery understanding how onclick changes work?

Tags: jquery, onclick, forms

Here is a simple jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


/*$(function() {
    // Sets the value of the submit_button_type field if the 'Submit & Add
    // Another button is clicked.
    $('#submit-id-submit_and_add').click(function() {
        $('#id_submit_button_type').val('submit_and_add');
    });
}); */

$('#submit-id-submit_and_add').click(function() {
        $('#id_submit_button_type').val('submit_and_add');
    });
}
```

what is the difference between the above two?
In the first, I have enclosed the click handler inside the function
In the second, I have defined it globally.

will the first function gets run twice once, upon the document ready and other, when button is clicked

The second way of defining globally, how does that work.
will it only be evaluated when the click happens

suppose my html is

```
<input id="id_submit_button_type" name="submit_button_type" type="hidden" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_and_add" value="Save &amp; Add Another" id="submit-id-submit_and_add"/>
```

I want to attach onclick in the input element something like

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_and_add" value="Save &amp; Add Another" id="submit-id-submit_and_add" onclick=somefunction/>
```

The somefunction will set the value for the input element here. how would I define somefunction in my js file, so that I could call it here. should that be wrapped inside $(document).ready(function() { }
such as

```
var somefunction=$('#submit-id-submit_and_add').click(function() {
            $('#id_submit_button_type').val('submit_and_add');
        });
    }
```

I am a beginner in Jquery. so these doubts could be silly. 
Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    <code>
});
```

is short for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    <code>
});
```

So the first version says to bind the handler after the document is ready. But since all the code is inside another document ready handler, it's already waiting for that event, so the extra wrapper has no effect. So the two versions are equivalent.

If you want a named function that does what the click handler does, you can do:

```
function somefunction() {
    $('#id_submit_button_type').val('submit_and_add');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-id-submit_and_add').click(somefunction);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! how would I attach onclick attribute in the form element and assign a corresponding function in the js file. (the last part of my question)

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do there. What is `somefunction()` supposed to do?

Comment: great!. do I i still need to have `$('#submit-id-submit_and_add').click(somefunction)` inside `document.ready` because I attach the handler in input element such as `<input type=submit onclick=somefunction name=submit_and_add />`

Comment: if you're binding the handler with `onclick="function()"` then you don't need that. They're two different ways of binding a click handler to an element. However, it's generally considered more idiomatic to use the jQuery binding instead of inline binding.

Comment: if I have named function like you have above, how is that function called unless I bind to `onclick=somefunction()`. inline binding is still calling jquery function correct? pardon me, I am an amateur in jquery, my questions could be silly

Comment: You either use `$(selector).click(functionname)` OR you put `onclick="functionname()"` in the element itself. They both do the same thing.